# php: getting my prepared statement result in an array

Tags: php, while-loop, prepared-statement

This is my code:

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare ( "SELECT album_no, album_name FROM $albumTable WHERE b_username=?  parent_name=? LIMIT 100" ))
        {

        $stmt->bind_param ( "ss", $a_owner,$p_name); // bind parameters for markers
        $stmt->execute ();
        $stmt->bind_result ($album_no,$album_name ); // bind result variables

        $stmt->fetch (); /* fetch value */

             if (isset ( $album_no ))
                {
                $array = array();
                $array['album_no']          = $album_no;
                $array['album_name']        = $album_name;
                }

        /* close statement */
        $stmt->close ();
        }

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close ();
```

and it works, the only problem is it returns just one row... I know I need a while() to go through the other rows but I just don't know where to put that while when using prepared statements :(
searching the docs I find "fetchAll()" but that seems to only work with "PDO" and I have no idea what PDO is :(

Thanks in advance

Comment: @Ryan PDO is an alternative to Mysqli. Quick intro here: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access--net-12059

Comment: Thanks JimL! Will check it out! But any really good reason to use PDO instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably what you're looking for:

```
$array = array();
while ($stmt->fetch()) 
{
    if (isset ($album_no))
    {
        $array['album_no'][]   = $album_no;
        $array['album_name'][] = $album_name;
    }
}
```

[`fetch()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php) fetches results from a prepared statement into the bound variables. Once there are no more rows to be returned, `fetch()` returns NULL and the loop body will not be executed any more.

Comment: Thanks, looks like what I am looking for, will try and if it works will select your answer

Answer (score 1):

You need to fetch in a loop:

```
while($stmt->fetch()) {
    ... do stuff with your bound variables
}
```

Once there's no more rows available for fetching, the fetch() call will return a false and terminate the while() loop.